# Python -- Why does a conditional execute in one function but does not in another?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner Python learner. I'm trying to write some basic code to automate a simple but repetitive work process, but got stumped by this problem.

```
# Prior to the code block below, a csv file import would have created the a and ag variables with their respective numerical values.

high = list(range(66, 99))
mod = list(range(36, 65))
low = list(range(1,35))
verysiggap = list(range(61, 99))
siggap = list(range(31, 60))
nonsiggap = list(range(1, 30))

fco_output_list = []

def fco_block1(*args):
    if a in high and ag in high:
        print("Both a and ag are high!")
        fco_output_list.append("fco1")
    if a in high and ag in high and a-ag in nonsiggap:
        fco_output_list.append("foc2")

fco_block1(a, ag)

a_ag_combi_output = 0
a_ag_gap_output = 0

def fco_block2(*args):
    global a_ag_combi_output
    if a in high and ag in high:
        a_ag_combi_output = 0
    elif a in high and ag in low or ag in mod:
        a_ag_combi_output = 1
    elif a in mod and ag in low:
        a_ag_combi_output = 2
    elif ag in high and a in low or a in mod:
        a_ag_combi_output = 3
    elif ag in mod and a in low:
        a_ag_combi_output = 4
    elif a in low and ag in low:
        a_ag_combi_output = 5
    global a_ag_gap_output
    if a in high and ag in high and a-ag in nonsiggap:
        a_ag_gap_output = 1

fco_block2(a, ag)

# There are some simple print functions after the code above that tell me very clearly that fco_block2 executed without any issues.
```

As for the execution of fco_block1, there are no error messages but the conditionals don't seem to be executing. Based on the imported values of a and ag, the fco_output_list should have been populated by fco1 and fco2, but it is not.

Why is this so? I find it bizarre especially when the conditionals in block1 are worded in the same way as the respective conditionals in block2, but those in block2 got executed and not those in block1?

Comment: The names in `foo_block1` are all global, except for `a` and `ag`. Those names are undefined. Where are you importing them? If you are passing them as arguments, though, you should access them as `args[0]` and `arg[1]` inside the function. (Or better yet, use real parameter names instead of `*args`.)

Comment: If you don't get an error message, then this isn't all of your code, since both a and ag are undefined (you don't need to pass them to the function at all)

Comment: I tried giving `a` and `ag` random values and it's working fine. Your code is really messy and your variables have confusing meaningless names so I won't be surprised if there's some renaming issue here, but my small test shows that this runs fine (or at least the first part)

Comment: The variables a and ag are imported from a csv file (I have lots of csv files to process daily) and the values for a and ag vary. In the above example, a = 99 and ag = 86.

Comment: okay. so you run this several times, and some of the numbers will result in an empty list, right? I mean if a is like 20 or 120 then the first function is gonna return an empty list. That's just reasonable

Comment: Also you don't need to repeat yourself, you check if both a and ag are in high twice

Comment: I ran it umpteenth times with the same csv file (where a = 99, ag = 86) over the past couple of hours to try figure out what's wrong. I've tried things like changing "if a in high and ag in high:" in fco_block1 to "if a > ag:" and it works fine i.e. the output list got populated with fco1. So I'm really stumped why "if a in high and ag in high:" in the first block doesn't seem to execute.

Sorry for all the confusing/meaningless variable names, they make sense for the csv file processing that I was hoping to automate. I didn't manage to change them to friendlier names for this question.

Comment: monke I don't know what's the problem, but the logic is ok. I made a cleaner version for you, hopefully that helps you locate where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the way you have defined the "high" list.

According to your comment: 
"I ran it umpteenth times with the same csv file **(where a = 99, ag = 86)**"

In Python the end values for "range" are exclusive (i.e. up to but **not** including), meaning that "list(range(66, 99))" will end in 98. Just to be clear, these are all the numbers in the "high" list:

```
[66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
```

As you can see, 99 is not there. So, for example, (a = 99, ag = 86) will fail because a is not in "high".

I tested your code with (a = 70, ag = 67) and it printed "Both a and ag are high!"

If you want ( a = 99, ag = 86) to trigger the print statement in fco_block1, change high to

```
high = list(range(66, 100))
```

Comment: This - python's ranges being open from the right - may very well be the issue. However, without concrete reproduction values for `a` and `ag`, we cannot be sure.

Comment: @Amitai Irron, The OP has provided concrete values in the comments above. The OP said "ran it umpteenth times with the same csv file (where a = 99, ag = 86) "

Comment: Indeed. Although they are hidden in the comments, where they should have been part of the code sample. Your answer, therefore, is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong, because your logic is ok. It's kinda bizarre and all over the place, but it's functional. The problem is probably elsewhere, either in the part where you process the data later or input the data. Whichever, I made a little cleaner more pythonic version, where one function does everything and the logic is way more readable. I also change `ag` into `b` because it makes more sense to me. I didn't test it, honestly, but I hope that a more readable code would help you locate the problem better

```
high       = list(range(66, 99))
mod        = list(range(36, 65))
low        = list(range(1,35))
verysiggap = list(range(61, 99))
siggap     = list(range(31, 60))
nonsiggap  = list(range(1, 30))

fco_output_list = []
a_b_gap_output = 0

def populate_fco(*args):
    if a in high:
        if b in high: #only check this once! 
            print("Both a and ag are high!")
            fco_output_list.append("fco1") #populate the list first

            if a-b in nonsiggap: #do the other check
                fco_output_list.append("foc2")
                a_b_gap_output = 1

            return 0 #finally return a result
        if b in low or b in mod:
            return 1 

    elif a in mod and b in low:
        return 2

    elif b in high:
        if a in low or a in mod:
            return 3

    elif b in mod and a in low:
        return 4

    elif a in low and b in low:
        return 5

#instead of this variable being used a million times, I just returned the result through the function while also populating the list
a_b_combi = populate_fco(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses! The comments have been very helpful especially for a Python newbie like me!